# Facebook Object Debugger showing old data / not updating

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags

When I check one of our url's in the object debugger, the debugger keeps showing old (cached) data under 'Object Properties'.

- However, the 'Raw Open Graph Document Information' is showing the actual data that it just got from our site.
- The Graph API shows a mix of old and current data.
- The scraped URL is actually showing the correct data, no cache, just the raw and actual live data it just scraped.

It is very confusing and it only seems to happen for one single page, the other pages work fine.
Link: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fqooqoon.com%2Fapple-iphone4s-invisible-shields-cases-screen-protectors-covers-skins.html

The code on our site:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="silqShield Invisible for Apple iPhone 4S">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://qooqoon.com/apple-iphone4s-invisible-shields-cases-screen-protectors-covers-skins.html">
<meta property="og:type" content="product">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://qooqoon.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/d58d44b981214661663244ef00ea7e30/4/s/4s-inv-screwdriver_1.jpg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="QooQoon">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1301384992">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="257717407574069">
```

Problems:

- Keeps linking to an old image url which is outdated
- Admin is defined, but the admin cannot see or access the admin to the page
- Shows an error about the og:type 'product' not being correct, but this is a known bug with Facebook and irrelevant to the problem
- Does not update any values on the Facebook Platform as it does with all our other url's/pages

It almost seems as if the URL is in some sort of deadlock where we have no control over.

Any tips / experiences with this?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you have right now is one of the og: tags appears to be interferring with the update.  Try removing it, for testing, and see if it resolves the issue.

> Object at URL
>   'http://qooqoon.com/apple-iphone4s-invisible-shields-cases-screen-protectors-covers-skins.html' of type 'og_products:product' is invalid because it the specified
>   fb:app_id '257717407574069' is not the owner of specified og:type

Comment: Thanks, this at least solves problem one. But there is a but... A quite huge one. Removing the og:type at least gets the right image etc. but it is now listed as a website and as far as I know it should still be a product.

Comment: The second problem that still remains is that even though I am the admin I can't see the page in my pages list. As far as I can see the error that the debugger throws is actually a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/285421101492706

Comment: PS: we changed back the og:type to product for now as the Facebook documentation clearly shows that it is a correct object property. We do however understand that the error that this throws is the reason for the problem of not updating the data.

Comment: You've gotta remember the og product tab is still beta and, in my humble opinion, should not be relied upon by companies in a production environment.  Since it is a bug, you can do the workaround and specify a type that allows the linter to work and pick up your images and admins.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. We were not aware that this type was in beta. In fact we have used it for over a year on all our other products without any problems. Also it is listed in several of Facebook's docs as a regular item which can be used with their native social plugins without any notice that it is beta.

Comment: According to some users on we might loose the built-up likes if we were to revert the type to website.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday Facebook fixed the bug which caused the problem. The problem is the og:type product was recognized as incorrect due to the new OpenGraph implementation. This has now been corrected and the debugger now does not throw any errors and it updates accordingly. The only real issue remaining is that we have no admin to certain pages.